# Can you use a swift/immediate action to interrupt an attack of opportunity?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, movement, opportunity-attack

***Scenario 1:***

Enemy A has [Greater Trip](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/greater-trip-combat/), allowing it to make an attack of opportunity on a successful trip. Player B has [Landing Roll](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/landing-roll-combat/), which lets him move 5 feet as an immediate action upon being tripped, before falling prone.

If A trips B, does it get to make the attack of opportunity before B has a chance to roll away?

***Scenario 2:***

Player C has both [Riptide Attack](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/riptide-attack-combat/), which allows him to drag as a swift action on a successful trip, and Greater Trip, as above.

If he trips something, can he drag it before making the AoO, or must the AoO come first?

Comment: ***Curiosity:*** Did a PC actually take the feat Landing Roll? (Those are some awfully beefy prerequisites for such a feat that *still* leaves you prone!)

Comment: No, this is just the simplest theoretical situation I could come up with to ask about this interaction, as funny as it would be to run with Monkey Style. The actual situation I'm looking at is the interaction between Greater Trip and Riptide Attack, and whether or not you can make the AoO after the drag.

Comment: How about asking the real question?

Comment: Because interrupting an enemy's AoO with an immediate action seems like it would come up more than interrupting your own with a swift action. I was just trying to make a question that's useful to more people. The same thing would come up with the spell Mental Barrier, for instance.

Comment: The site wants to help *you.* If helping you helps others, so be it, but that's entirely secondary to the site answering *your* question. Ask the real one you want an answer to, and let the site do the work.

Comment: @HeyICanChan From the Help Center, "How Do I Ask a Good Question?":

"Make it relevant to others
We like to help as many people at a time as we can. Make it clear how your question is relevant to more people than just you, and more of us will be interested in your question and willing to look into it."

Comment: @aryst0krat One reason the site prefers questions that arise during play (rather than speculative questions) is that chances are the same questions will arise or have arisen during play for others, too. The site accommodates *relevant to others* naturally, without the asker needing to ask one question but hoping that its answers will address the asker's real, secret question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greater Trip (unlike the D&D 3.5e version of Improved Trip that it’s partially based on) is ambiguous as to its timing: it says the target provokes an attack of opportunity when you successfully trip, but since attacks of opportunity usually interrupt the provoking action, that might mean that you AoO them while they’re still standing.

We can reject that possibility, however, on the ground that it could result in an arbitrary number of attacks: since the target is not prone, you can trip them again, provoking more AoOs. Since you are tripping and not attacking, this would be pointless—unless you have nearby allies with Combat Reflexes who can benefit.

Clearly, that is not a good thing to introduce to the game. We thus rule that the AoO occurs after the target is prone. That resolves the question regarding Landing Roll: since that occurs before falling prone, and Greater Trip’s AoO happens after, Landing Roll must occur first (and thus can potentially allow the target to avoid the AoO).

Riptide Attack is much more ambiguous. There is no clear ordering here, and furthermore it’s not clear that, after you have used one or the other, you are still eligible to use whichever you didn’t use immediately after the trip. It seems unconscionable to me that Paizo didn’t explicitly clarify this situation, when Greater Trip and Riptide Attack share so many prerequisites and are obviously going to be considered together.

As for ruling, you should allow them to both be used, in whichever order the tripper likes; it’s a minor thing, really, but Pathfinder melee types need an the help they can get.